Issue in search with join in typesense
I want to search with the tag name and dish name.
I tried this but it did not work
const data = await typesenseClient.collections("dishes_view").documents().search({
    'q': 'tag1',
    'query_by': '*',
    "filter_by": "$dish_tags(id: *)",
    "include_fields": "$tags(*) as as tagsData ,name"
    
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));

Is there any mistake in my search query or is typesense not providing a search in the join table?
If there is any mistake in my query please provide the correct search query. Is there any other to implement this functionality
This is my collection Schema
const schema={
  "name": "dishes",
  "num_documents": 0,
  "fields": [
    { "name": "id", "type": "string", "facet": false },
    { "name": "name", "type": "string", "facet": false },
    { "name": "unit", "type": "int32", "facet": false, "optional": true },
    { "name": "calories", "type": "int32", "facet": false, "optional": true },
    { "name": "price", "type": "int32", "facet": false },
    { "name": "is_active", "type": "bool", "facet": false },
    { "name": "size", "type": "int32", "facet": false, "optional": true },
  ],
  "default_sorting_field": "created_at",
  "enable_nested_fields": true
}

const schema = {
  "name": "tags",
  "num_documents": 0,
  "fields": [
    { "name": "id", "type": "string", "facet": false },
    { "name": "name", "type": "string", "facet": false }     
  ],
  "enable_nested_fields": true}

const schema = {
  "name": "dish_tags",
  "num_documents": 0,
  "fields": [
    { "name": "dish_id", "type": "string", "facet": false, "reference": "dishes_view.id" },
    { "name": "tags_id", "type": "string", "facet": false, "reference": "tags.id" }
  ],
  "enable_nested_fields": true
}


Typesense does not natively support joins like a traditional SQL database. Instead, you typically denormalize your data to include the necessary information within a single document.

Yes it does: https://typesense.org/docs/27.0/api/joins.html
